# How to move gcno files to a folder when building with gcc

Tags: c, gcc, test-coverage

I have a make option specified as

```
gcc -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage -fPIC -fprofile-dir="./build" test.c -o build/test.out
```

With the above option the `gcda` files are moved to build directory but not the `gcno` files...

How do we move  the gcno files to the build folder?

Comment: _The .gcno files are placed in the **same directory** as the object file. By default, the .gcda files are also stored in the same directory as the object file, but the GCC -fprofile-dir option may be used to store the .gcda files in a separate directory._ See [10.4 Brief Description of gcov Data Files](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Gcov-Data-Files.html)

Comment: yes that is what the documentation says but if I build from /code directory and the build folder is @ /code/build then it does not place the .gcno files in  the build folder instead it places it @ /code folder.

Comment: Sounds like either a code or documentation bug.